# Is there a way to replicate AWS managed Redis to Azure managed Redis in real time?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, azure-redis-cache

I have tried below approach .
 
Step 1) Took a snapshot of AWS Redis and copied it in Azure
Step 2) Listened to the key space notifications from AWS Redis and put it in a Queue and read these events from the queue and applied it on Azure Redis.

Problems faced:
1)Every operation which effects AWS Redis data, needs one query to AWS Redis to get the effected data as it is not present in notification.
2) Some operations like 'rename' is being delivered in two notifications, handling these two notifications to construct the actual operation will be bit difficult even in Queue.